# Create new Spark DataFrame when looping through rdd.collect()

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a Spark dataframe `df2`. I am doing a `for row in df2.rdd.collect():`

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([
          ["PROG1","ACTION1","11","IN PROGRESS"],
          ["PROG2","ACTION2","12","NEW"],
          ["PROG3","ACTION1","20","FINISHED"],
          ["PROG4","ACTION4","14","IN PROGRESS"],
          ["PROG5","ACTION1","20","NEW"]
],["PROGRAM_NAME", "ACTION", "VALUE1", "STATUS"])

for row in DF2.rdd.collect():
   # Update sharepoint using patch and get response from Sharepoint (already have the code for this)
```

**Asking help on how to:**

Take all rows from `df2`, add a new column `RESPONSE` and create a new data frame `df3`.

This is how both Data frame should look like

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply update each row in your for loop, by adding new field `RESPONSE`, to create a new `rdd3` from which you create data frame `df3`:

```
rdd3 = []
for row in df2.rdd.collect():
    # other staff here
    api_response = 200  # set the one from Sharepoint
    rdd3.append(Row(**row.asDict(), RESPONSE=api_response))

df3 = spark.createDataFrame(rdd3, df2.columns + ["RESPONSE"])

df3.show()

#+------------+-------+------+-----------+--------+
#|PROGRAM_NAME| ACTION|VALUE1|     STATUS|RESPONSE|
#+------------+-------+------+-----------+--------+
#|       PROG1|ACTION1|    11|IN PROGRESS|     200|
#|       PROG2|ACTION2|    12|        NEW|     200|
#|       PROG3|ACTION1|    20|   FINISHED|     200|
#|       PROG4|ACTION4|    14|IN PROGRESS|     200|
#|       PROG5|ACTION1|    20|        NEW|     200|
#+------------+-------+------+-----------+--------+
```

Comment: Getting error 


TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'PROGRAM_NAME'

Comment: @Avi I am able to run this code without any error in spark (versions 3 and 2.4). Have you tried this code as it is without adding your logic?

Comment: Worked after calling from pyspark.sql import Row